# Ckeditor5 plugin not showing in toolbar

Tags: ckeditor5, ckeditor5-plugin, drupal-10

I have created custom plugin in ckeditor5 witb drupal10. I have made the necessary changes in ckeditor5.yml but the plugin is not showing in toolbar items when i am configuring in editor.I have made the changes in block widget of ckedito5.i have use dev_starter_template for drupal

```
type here
```